# Can items be stacked in one location for easier animation?

Tags: animation, cloth-simulation, collision, soft-body

[image]I am building a softbody Tetris animation and am manually placing the pieces above the container above each other, then animating them into position before they drop.

Is it possible/reasonable to have them all start in the same location without having the cloth sim/collision freak out?

The drops/movements/rotations themselves are animated using the NLA editor on the handles.

Comment: It's 3D. So you can stack them along the Y-axis, one behind the other, can't you? Alternatively, you can [keyframe the collision](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/collision.html). There is an ["eye" icon](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/_images/physics_collision_toggle.png) in the *Collision* section in the *Physics Properties* tab that enables/disables it. You can keyframe this toggle (hover it and press `I` - or use the context menu) so the simulation should not freak out.

Comment: If i move them in the Y i still have to keyframe them into position to fall in. It’s the same issue. I tried the collision thing before posting and as far as i could tell it just hides the visibility of the simulation, it still collides behind the scenes ruining the meshes and turning them into a mess. The moment the visibility is turned back on they are a crumpled ball of vertices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can, just animate the collision "eye" at the start of your animation with the same value, what your simulation start value is:

[image]

so here in my example, i enable collision (keyframe) on frame 50, because my simulation starts at 50.

result:

[image]

Comment: Perfect thank you!

Comment: you are welcome